# Cloudera CDH3 installation failure, how to get around this?

Tags: hadoop, system-administration, cloudera

I am attempting to install CHD3 onto a 3 node cluster.  I launch the installations via the Cloudera Manager.  All three installations fail.

I see this error after the Cloudera installation fails in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.out:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py", line 19, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/psutil-0.3.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    TOTAL_PHYMEM = _psplatform.phymem_usage()[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/psutil-0.3.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 122, in phymem_usage
    percent = usage_percent(total - (free + buffers + cached), total,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Apparently the Python interpreter running on start up sees "free", "buffers", or "cached" as having a NoneType and this error causes the entire installation to roll back.

Can anyone advise as to why this occurs and/or a way around the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rerunning the installation fails with the following message in  /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/5.init-embedded-db.log: /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data is non-empty; perhaps the database was already initialized?

Comment: $ sudo ls /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data
base                    pg_clog        pg_log        pg_subtrans  PG_VERSION       postmaster.opts
generated_password.txt  pg_hba.conf    pg_multixact  pg_tblspc    pg_xlog
global                  pg_ident.conf  pg_stat_tmp   pg_twophase  postgresql.conf
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/
total 4
drwx------ 12 cloudera-scm cloudera-scm 4096 Jun 17 00:08 data

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to run CDH3?  I have installed CDH3 and CDH4.  There are "undocumented" things you need to do where installing CDH3.  I spent hours on the phone with Cloudera to get it up and working.  CDH4 installed very easy.

Comment: I just had the same problems after removing the /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data directory and rerunning the installation on the three machines in my cluster.  The three installations failed and rolled back when the Cloudera Manager Agent could not be started.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, in phymem_usage() in _pslinux.py:

```
def phymem_usage():
    # total, used and free values are matched against free cmdline utility
    # the percentage matches top/htop and gnome-system-monitor
    f = open('/proc/meminfo', 'r')
    try:
        total = free = buffers = cached = None
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('MemTotal:'):
                total = int(line.split()[1]) * 1024
            elif line.startswith('MemFree:'):
                free = int(line.split()[1]) * 1024
            elif line.startswith('Buffers:'):
                buffers = int(line.split()[1]) * 1024
            elif line.startswith('Cached:'):
                cached = int(line.split()[1]) * 1024
                break
        used = total - free
        percent = usage_percent(total - (free + buffers + cached), total,
                                _round=1)
        return ntuple_sysmeminfo(total, used, free, percent)
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Note that it is examining /proc/meminfo and is converting fields to integers without checking if those fields exist. On some systems, including some virtualization technologies, Buffers or Cache may be missing. (The LSB spec states that most of these fields are optional.)

A quick fix would be to change /proc/meminfo to /tmp/meminfo, "cat /proc/meminfo >/tmp/meminfo", and add a line like:

Buffers:             0 kB

Comment: There is information here too: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/psutil/lSE54S4iPd0